# Toolbar buttons disappeared in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea 2017.2.4 and two buttons on the bottom toolbar have disappeared. The two buttons are "Run" (Alt+4) and "Debug" (Alt+5). I can find them in the pop-up menu in the bottom left corner of Idea either and pressing Alt+4 and Alt+5 doesn't work even though the default keymap setup has not been changed.

Is there a way to get them back without having to reinstall Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they re-appear on the bottom toolbar and in the pop-up menu when I right-click a file and select either run or debug. The key bindings work again as well.